# What can I use instead of a while loop that will check something over and over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button whose function is

```
def callback2():
    callback()
```

The `callback()` function is

```
def callback():
    usein = None
    if inspect.stack()[1][3] == callback2:
        global inputText
        usein = inputText.get()
        return None
    while True: #freezes everything, because tkinter
        if usein:
            return usein
```

Now, the reason I have to do it like this is because other functions call `callback()` looking for the value inputted by the button, but I have to make them wait for the button to be pressed. But since I'm using tkinter, the while loop doesn't work - it just makes the GUI freeze. So what can I use instead? I've been working on this for days. I'd be glad to add any other parts of my code if needed.

Comment: wait, so `callback` will do something different whether it was called by `callback2` or not? That seems wrong... why are multiple things calling the one function if it's doing different things depending on the caller?

Comment: You should set a flag and whatever sets `usein` should check that flag if set return whatever `usein` returns

Comment: Your `while` loop freezing everything has nothing to do with Tkinter; there's no way for `usein` to change within the loop, so if it doesn't exit immediately, there's no way for it to ever exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
isButtonClicked = false #a global variable
def callback2():
    isButtonClicked = true
    callback()
    isButtonClicked = false
```

One idea may be to use a global variable called isButtonClicked and assign a false value, and modify the other methods which call callback method like this:

```
def othermethod():
if isButtonClicked:
    callback()
```

But you've to make sure that the variables are thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not a tkinter expert, but if you want to get some text input on a button click, the following may work.

```
def callback():
    usein = entry.get()
    # do whatever with usein

master = Tk()
entry = Entry(master)  # the text input
Button(master, text='Button', command=callback)
```